# Recursive class in R

Tags: r, reference-class

i'm trying to do an "node" Class in R, like in java:
but the code pop up an error, "The class node doesn't exist when i'm creating the value "Next="node"
is it not possible to do recursion in a class in R? or how could i do this?

```
node <- setRefClass("node", fields = list(value="numeric", next="node"))
```

> Error: inesperado '=' in "node <- node <- setRefClass("node", fields = list(value="numeric", next=""

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using the flow `Control` word `next`. Try `help(next)` and this description comes up

> These are the basic control-flow constructs of the R language. They function in much the same way as control statements in any Algol-like language. **They are all reserved words.**

As such they cannot be used for variable names, and if they are used for list names they should be quoted. Eg. this will work:

```
setRefClass('node', fields = list(value = 'numeric', 'next' = 'node'))
```

note that I wrote `'next'` and not `next`
As a side note I would suggest checking out the `R6` package, which provides a simpler interface to OOP than reference classes while also being **much** faster than reference classes.